# The trait bound `T: std::default::Default` is not satisfied when using PhantomData<T>

Tags: rust

In my current project, I am trying to write something that can be represented by this minimal example:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct A<T> {
    field: std::marker::PhantomData<T>
}

struct B;

fn main() {
    let a = A::<B> {
        ..Default::default()
    };
}
```

However, this code does not compile.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `B: std::default::Default` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:11
   |
10 |         ..Default::default()
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `B`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::default::Default` for `A<B>`
   = note: required by `std::default::Default::default`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Which for me, is a little bit strange, as `Default` is derived for `A` and for `PhantomData<T>`, so why does it matter if it's not implemented for `B`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout the link from @mcarton, because [manually implementing the default trait does compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=a843fc231252847d7b5f17c340d6c23f).

```
//#[derive(Default)]
struct A<T> {
    field: std::marker::PhantomData<T>
}

struct B;

impl<T> Default for A<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self { field: Default::default() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A::<B> {
         ..Default::default()
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be exactly the thing addressed by https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2353